# Mysql "where" and "or" statement

Tags: mysql

I started to work on a Mysql query abut it keeps coming up with a error?

can some one look at it and tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
$query = ("select * from `users` where (`username`='$username' and `password`='$password' or select * from `users` where `$username `='$email' and `password`='$password')");
```

the error is

```
 mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/a8423624/public_html/testchecklogin.php on line 57
```

which means that it hasn't found anyone. This means that my Query is wrong?

Comment: Showing the SQL isn't enough to solve a PHP error.

Comment: can you put an error string here? mysql_error() return the error.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `... OR SELECT...` is giving the error. I think you are trying to write that as:

```
$query = ("select * from `users` where (`username`='$username' OR `$username `='$email') and `password`='$password'");
```

Comment: I believe `\`$username \`` should also be `\`username\``

Comment: I assume `'$username'` is a php variable

Comment: @mac yer it was and @Tudor Constantin yer it is this is a submit form that will let the user log into my website with their username or Email

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

```
select * from `users` 
where 
(`username`='$username' or `username `='$email') and `password`='$password'
```

Comment: I think you have to add some paranthesis to group the `OR` clause, so that it will be evaluated before the `AND` one

Answer (score 1):

Works!

```
SELECT * FROM "users" WHERE (username = '".$username."' OR username = '".$email."') AND password = '".$password."'";
```